# Unwanted content getting translated

Tags: web8.5, translation-manager, worldserver

Currently we are using web 8.5 and sending components in bundle for translation and checking its status in translation manager. We have encountered an issue and I am fairly new to translation module and need help in understanding the root cause.

```
     <p>This is a sample by [[authorName]].<br/>Contact me at [[authorEmail]]</p>
```

Above is a sample text in rtf when inspected in world server source view, authorEmail is enclosed in embed tag whereas authorName isn’t enclosed in embed tag and getting translated. We did not find this embed tag in cms side and aren’t sure where it is being added in or before sending to world server. We think, due to embed tag not being added to authorName the text in double quotes is being translated which shouldn’t be.

```
    <p>This is a sample by [[authorName]].</p><br/><p>Contact me at [[authorEmail]]</p>
```

For testing we sent text in rtf as above closing the p tag before br tag and opening p tag after br tag then we could see authorName also enclosed in embed tag.

Comment: By default, Tridion Sites wouldn't add the wrapping double brackets  to content as its stored in the CMS. Do the brackets appear if you check the version history in Tridion Sites before, during, or after sending items to translation?

Comment: And do you happen to know if the Translation Manager setup was customized (e.g., with custom ITS rules)? I'll try to ask around but I suspect the brackets and/or those words are being handled on the WorldServer side.

Comment: Double brackets are intentional specified by cms author in Tridion to specify the text which would later be replaced by web code with actual value. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Okay, does the mention of "double quotes" above really refer to double brackets?

Comment: I added an answer based on what I know for Tridion Sites and WorldServer. I think by default the double-bracketed text would appear as _translatable_ in WS or Computer-aided translation (CAT) client/tool like Trados Studio. So there's likely a specific segmentation rule or configuration to put things like `authorName` in embed tags.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange.

By default, the double-bracketed text *would* be translatable, as seen by translators in Trados Studio, for example, as segments to translate with the rest of the text. I'll describe the translation process from Tridion Sites to WorldServer from what I know to hopefully highlight a few places for you to check.

### From Tridion Sites

As part of the [translation process](https://docs.rws.com/1099765/107169/tridion-sites-10-main-documentation/translation-manager-system-diagram), Translation Manager gathers the requested items to translate and converts them to the [`.ITS` format, which is a format governed by W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-i18n-bp/#Generic) and recognized by various translation systems, such as WorldServer, TMS, or Trados Enterprise.

In general, Tridion Sites marks entire fields as translatable or not, based on the Schema settings. However, the ITS Rules can be modified in the TranslationManager.XHTML.ITS.Rules.xml file (see the [documentation](https://docs.rws.com/1099765/123065/tridion-sites-10-main-documentation/writing-its-rules)). These rules adjust how the XML translates, so it might be worth checking if these might have been customized.

### To WorldServer

On the translation side, World Server's filters handle the `.ITS` file format sent by Tridion Sites through Translation Manager. The format is [configured as a "custom component" in WorldServer](https://docs.rws.com/975503/102237/worldserver-11-8-user-documentation/adding-the-application-its-xml-mime-type).

From what I understand from colleagues quite familiar with WorldServer, that double-bracket syntax and contained words would appear as translatable segments by default, at least to the system.

For example, my colleague shared this from a screenshot in Trados Studio of a similar setup, without customization.

[image: source and target translation segments]

Note that the `<p>` tag has been explicitly recognized as a tag, however, the double-bracketed text just appears as source text in the segments on the left, with the text on the right ready to be translated to some expected target language.

Perhaps the [segmentation process](https://docs.rws.com/975503/487589/worldserver-11-8-user-documentation/the-segmentation-process-in-------------worldserver) and filter has been customized for the ITS format (e.g., for .cmp files)? It would be worth following up with your project management office (PMO) or project manager on the localization side (or your localization team if internal). Otherwise submit an [RWS Gateway ticket](https://gateway.sdl.com/) to further investigate the setup.